# Eclipse: keep getting "ERROR: Application requires API version 15. Device API version is 14 (Android 4.0.2)."

Tags: android, eclipse, target

I've been testing an Android app on a device that had API version 15 installed. I now have to switch to a different device (a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, if it matters) that has version 14. Even though I changed "project build target" from Google APIs 15 to 14, I still get the following message when I try to execute the app on the new device:

**ERROR: Application requires API version 15. Device API version is 14 (Android 4.0.2).**

Cleaning all projects did not help. Restarting Eclipse did not help. I created a simple new test app with target=14 and it worked fine.

Why changes to the old project are not taking effect?

Thanks!

Comment: Something in the manifest like <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" /> maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the `minSdkVersion` in your `AndrodManifest.xml`. See [this post](https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts/LaHVTVHoHRe) and the [blog entry](http://simonvt.net/2012/02/07/what-api-level-should-i-target/) it is based on for details.